# How to create gravity button on tableview in ios swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3, gravity

how to create green floating button on tableview?.Please refer the below image.When i tried to drag a button on tableview its added as cell dont know much about the layer and views concepts.Please help.

[image: green button]

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the title of your question really. But I assume you want a floating button fixed at right corner below.

I have also done the same thing. Do not add the button above tableView. Add button first and then place tableView.Please see the hierarchy as shown below. I got the result by this. Hope you get as well.

[image] 
[image]

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    floatingAddButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * floatingAddButton.bounds.size.width
    floatingAddButton.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

If you are going to hide the button when you scroll the tableView then you can add `floatingAddButton.isHidden = true` in viewDidload().
Detect the end of scroll and show the floating button again. 
Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer i followed your step but its not working in my case m trying to place this button on tableview.

Comment: You want the button fixed at the bottom right corner right?? Just like we have Gmail app on mobile..It shouldn't scroll with tableView..

Comment: hi bela can you help me to solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111242/how-we-can-pass-default-null-value-in-parameter-list-while-posting-a-request-to/48111394#48111394

Comment: @deltami hi.. If passing values is compulsory You can pass 0 for Int type keys and nil for String type. Later change the values when necessary. I will post the answer but I need some time. Please mention what is expected or post the request image or something

Comment: hey bella thank you so much.you can check my updated question.I will wait for your answer.

Comment: @deltami hi.. I don't have enough rep to post a comment there.... Is  "formattedArray", "date1", "date2" of String type?

Comment: yes bella its of string type only.In fact every parameter is of string type.

Answer (score 0):

You should do this using Storyboard.

In following way you can do this.

[image: main.storyboard]