# How we can pass default null value in parameter list of dictionary [String:String] while posting a request to server ? Swift3

Tags: swift3, http-post

In some case i have to post null values to server either as a default value or as a parameter's value.I tried many ways but it didnt work.I'm using Alamofire for posting a request.Please help.

**Method-1**

```
   var empty : String = ""
   let parameters = ["User-Id":userId,"search_cat": formattedArray ?? empty,"date1":ab ?? empty,"date2" : bc ?? empty,"docname" : empty
        ] as! [String : String]
```

**Method-2**

```
   let parameters = ["User-Id":userId,"search_cat": formattedArray ?? "","date1":ab ?? "","date2" : bc ?? "","docname" : ""
        ] as! [String : String]
```

**Method-3**

```
 var nullvalue : String = ""
    if formattedArray == nil
    {
        formattedArray = ""
        print(formattedArray)

    }
    if ab == nil
    {
        ab = ""
        print(ab)

    }
    if bc == nil
    {
        bc = ""
        print(bc)

    }
    if nullvalue == nil
    {
        nullvalue = ""
    }
    parameters = ["User-Id":userId,"search_cat": formattedArray,"date1":ab ,"date2" : bc ,"docname" : nullvalue ] 
      as! [String : String]
```

**Method - 4** According to answer i changed parameterlist dictionary to [String:AnyObject] but still it's not working.And giving me the error.

```
var ab:String?
var bc : String?
var formattedArray: String?

parameters = ["User-Id":userId ,"search_cat": formattedArray ?? NSNull() ,
"date1":ab ?? NSNull() ,"date2" : bc ?? NSNull(),
"docname" :  NSNull()] as! [String : AnyObject]
```

**Method-4** giving me **Error while trying to set formattedArray ?? NSNull() : 
Cannot convert value of type 'NSNull' to expected argument type 'String'** 
with rest of the parameters its working fine.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED :**   is this that you want?

```
class RequestParameter : NSObject{

var formattedArray : String!
var date1 : String!
var date2 : String!
var docName : String!
var userId : String!      // or whatever if hardCoded

func param() -> NSDictionary{

   var param : [String : String] = [:]

   param["User-Id"] = userId
   param["search_cat"] = formattedArray
   param["date1"] = date1
   param["date2"] = date2
   param["docname"] = docName

   return param as! NSDictionary
  }
}
```

You can call these parameters where ever required. like 
`var reqParam = RequestParameter()`
`reqParam.param()`

I am really unaware of your Request parameter type. For eg. should it look like **date1** = *nil* or something else. 
This is all I could answer you. If wrong maybe someone might ans better.

Good Luck!!

Comment: my parameter list is of type [String:String] not [String:Any] coz bella if it was type of [String:Any] then will set NSNull().

Comment: tell me one thing is "search_cat" key always null or the value changes to String later(in request)

Comment: Do you use Postman to check the request and response..if yes, then can you post an image of how the request is in Postman.

Comment: not always null that will depend upon the selection if will not choose any of date1 from UI then it should be consider null otherwise whatever date i selected.

Comment: Hi @deltami.... what if you try `parameters = [String : Any]()` or try `(formattedArray as? AnyObject) ?? NSNull()`

Answer (score 0):

I actually had the same issue a couple of days ago and solved it using NSNull().

When converting my class I want to send the videoUrl property regardless of it containing a value, so that the backend can update it in the DB.

```
dict["videoUrl"] = videoUrl ?? NSNull()
```

This will set the key "videoUrl" with the value of the property videoUrl, or if nil, an instance of NSNull().

Express.js then reads this as undefined and inserts a null value to the database.

[image: Null value]

EDIT: I saw one of your comments below. When using a Dictionary of type [String:String], you will never be able to pass a nil value.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i tried to pass this :         parameters = ["User-Id":userId ,"search_cat": formattedArray ?? NSNull() ,"date1":ab ?? NSNull() ,"date2" : bc ?? NSNull()  ,"docname" :  NSNull()] as! [String : AnyObject]              but its giving me the error : Cannot convert value of type 'String!' to expected argument type '_?'

Comment: hey please check my updated question and help me out if you can.:(

Comment: @deltami Please try [String:Any] instead. And don't use `as! [String:Any]`, that is casting. When declaring a type you do that after the variable name, like `let somethingSomething: [String: Any] = [.....]`.